# txt is being created when using the local windows debugger but is not being created when I launch the application from the debug folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

```cpp
std::string username, password;

std::cout << "Enter a username: ";
std::cin >> username;
std::cout << "Enter a password: ";
std::cin >> password;

std::ofstream userFile;
userFile.open("../Login System\\" + username + ".txt");
userFile << username << std::endl << password;
userFile.close();
```

I have this piece of code that allows a user to register a username and password and it creates a text file in the folder specified when I launch the application from the Windows Local Debugger. However, when I launch the application from the debug folder, no text file is being created. Is this a VS2019 issue or did I do something wrong in the code?

Comment: I think it is created, only not in a place where you look for it. Have you tried a drive-wide file search?

Comment: After calling `userFile.open`, you should call [`userFile.is_open`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/is_open) to make sure the file opened successfully.

Comment: Also note that since you are using a relative path when opening the file, the location of the text file will depend on how the application is launched.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the `ofstream.open` function, if the specified file name is not an absolute path, the `open` function will automatically call GetCurrentDirectory and add the full path to the file.

Therefore, when you use a relative path `../Login System\\`, the `open` function will find the path where the current program is located. So, the `.txt` will not appear in `../Login System\\` if there is no such path in the current program directory.

Then, I tested the following code and it worked.

```
userFile.open("../Debug\\" + username + ".txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the working directory (aka current directory) are different in the two cases you are testing. The path you are using is relative and the working directory is used to convert that to an absolute path. When running you program form inside visual studio the working directory is the project folder (by default) but if you double click your exe in explorer, the working directory will be the folder the exe resides in.

That being said, keep in mind that if a folder does not exists (or is not found based on current working directory) the `ofstream.open` will not create it. Therefore it can not open the file.